# Integrating Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I have one Application in which i have to show **All wall Post** of facebook user.
we can post a message on a wall, and upload an image.
But i don't have any idea about getting all Wall post in our application whether its is possible or not.
But default android facebook application provides this feature so it must be possible.

Tell me how to get **All Wall Posts** Of Facebook User?

Comment: Yes u can able to do that. Use facebook api and see some demo like: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/

Comment: Hello bindalbhai.. How r u? R u der?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done Getting all wallpost By using Hackbook for android demo on devloper.android.com 
By using Graph api 
Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Facebook SDK for android

> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

also Facebook Android Tutorial

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/